# Where is function's declaration in bash?

Tags: bash, function, include

In my script in bash, there are lot of included libs and I use functions declared in these files. Like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
. foo.inc
. bar.inc
. baz.inc

function_1
function_2
function_3

EOF
```

My question is how to learn which file include function_1 declaration? In runtime of this script.

Comment: Why don't you look into foo.inc, bar.inc, and baz.inc?

Comment: If I will add new include, I'll have to add new code to my search function.

Answer (score 1):

You don't know. You'll have to grep the included files for the definition

Comment: Then you must not include them. Sorry I don't understand your issue fully. 

If you include the files you depend on them

Comment: I don't want to add new grep, when I include new lib...

type -t function_1 can tell that this is a function
type -f ping can tell where is the file
May be there is a way to learn in which file my function defined...?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

In your script, add the following line:

```
shopt -s extdebug
```

then you can retrieve the source filename and the line number in that file that the function definition begins on:

```
def=($(declare -F function_1))
echo "function name: ${def[0]}"
echo "line number: ${def[1]}"
echo "file name: ${def[@]:2}"  # the array slice makes it work even if the filename contains spaces
```

**Original answer:**

You shouldn't need to know at runtime which file provided a function. Perhaps if you posted your code, we could better see what you need.

When you source a file (using "`. foo.inc`" for example), it's as if it were actually in the main file.

If you need, for some reason, to know if it's loaded yet, you could do something ugly (akin to kids in the car crying "are we there yet?" every few seconds):

```
function_check ()
{
    local fn found notfound;
    for fn in $function_list;
    do
        if [[ -n $(declare -F $fn) ]]; then
            found+=$fn" ";
        else
            notfound+=$fn" ";
        fi;
    done;
    echo $found;
    function_list=$notfound
}

function_list="function_1 function_2 function_3"

. foo.inc
foo_list=$(function_check)

. bar.inc
bar_list=$(function_check)

. baz.inc    
baz_list=$(function_check)

echo "Warning: the following functions were not found: $function_list"
```

The function `function_check` checks for the existence of functions listed in `$function_list` and if found echoes them and removes them from the list. (Say that fast three times!)

**Edit**:

Here's a way to do what I think may be very close to what you want:

In **each** of your functions, add a test for an option that returns its source like this:

```
function_1 ()
{
    if [[ $1 == "--source" ]]
    then
        echo "source: ${BASH_SOURCE}"
        return
    fi

    # do your function stuff
}
```

Then in your script, you can source the files containing the functions and to find the source of a particular function:

```
function_1 --source
```

will echo the filename it came from. And of course you can act on it:

```
if [[ $(function_1 --source) == /some/dir/file ]]
then
    do_something
fi
```