# How would one get a list of functions in a shell script?

Tags: linux, list, function, shell, typeset

I want to generate a list of all functions in a shell script (a shell script function library that I am sourcing). Currently, I am experimenting with typeset in ways such as the following:

```
typeset -f
typeset -F
typeset -F | awk -F"declare -f " '{print $2}' | grep -v '_'
```

A difficulty I am having is that some functions which are not in the function library are listed and I don't know how to excise these from the function listing or how to generate the function listing in a better way. I would welcome any ideas you may have on this.

A bonus would be to generate a function listing in the order in which the functions appear in the shell script.

Comment: If you only want the functions that are in the function library (presumably some well-known directory), then why not just list the function library?  Which shell are you using?

Comment: I'm using Bash. I would like to have a listing of the names of the functions in the script. The difficulty in parsing the script library file is that the formatting of the text used for the declaration of functions can change between functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume bash is the shell.
typeset (or declare ) show the current environment, functions are part of the environment:

- there's no inherent ordering in the environment (names are sorted on output)
- the unwanted functions may be inherited from the environment, having been previously been 
  marked for export with declare -x

You could experiment with "env" to start your script in a clean environment, try:

```
env -i "PATH=$PATH" "TERM=$TERM" "LANG=$LANG" myscript.sh
```

as starting point.

The best way to enumerate functions in bash is documented here: [Where is function's declaration in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444078/where-is-functions-declaration-in-bash)
Note that "declare -F" does not normalise the filename, it will be as invoked/sourced.

```
while read xx yy fn; do
    func=( $(shopt -s extdebug; declare -F $fn) )
    printf  "%-30s %4i %-30s\n" "${func[@]:2}" "${func[1]}" "${func[0]}"
done < <(declare -F)
```

All you need to do is filter by the required filename, and sort by line number.

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance. The ordering trick is clean and useful.

Answer (score 1):

One approach I have is as follows (where the code is contained in the function library script):

```
initialListOfFunctionsInEnvironment="$(typeset -F | awk -F"declare -f " '{print $2}')"
# declare functions
finalListOfFunctionsInEnvironment="$(typeset -F | awk -F"declare -f " '{print $2}')"
diff  <(echo "${initialListOfFunctionsInEnvironment}" ) <(echo "${finalListOfFunctionsInEnvironment}") | grep -E '^(<|>)' | awk -F"> " '{print $2}'
```

This seems to produce a simple list of all functions that are added to the environment when the function library script is sourced. Criticism of this approach would be appreciated.